# How to get a webpage's source code or text contents

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I am familiar with Javascript, HTML, VBScript, PHP, and MySQL. I am trying to create my own webpage change monitoring program for personal use (Work related). I need a sample code I can study/analyze that can visit a website and copy all the text contents or perhaps the source code. I will then save that copied data into MySQL database or wherever, then I want to be able to get the contents of that webpage again and compare it to the one I stored to MySQL, this is so I can periodically check if there were changes on the websites we are constantly monitoring.

I prefer to build my own and I prefer to do it in Javascript, I do not want to start learning JQuery, is this doable? I know about innerhtml as well but that is for a webpage you own or have access to.

I have searched for this answer for a while now and couldn't get a single idea to beggin with so I have not made any codes to do this yet.

Jay

Comment: You can retrieve content of URL using PHP `file_get_content` function. Then store it. However if website has some ajax content you will not get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my extent of knowledge this is not possible in JavaScript. Yet you can do that in PHP, it can get the source code of most HTML, JS and CSS files, yet of course not PHP source code, only the generated HTML code. You first get the contents of the page using "file_get_contents" and save it to the MySQL database. Then if your statement of mastering PHP is correct, you can write your own code to compare both source codes, that's easy enough.

**Sample Code:**

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (WebPage1Source)
VALUES
('$source')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no I haven't mastered PHP, I'm just familiar with it that's why I'm struggling. I was able to learn about file_get_contents and strip_tags though, thanks everyone for the help :)